# Cannot remove double vertices

Tags: mesh, vertices

I tried to follow a tutorial , which showed to remove double vertices in blender by pressing F3 and typing "Remove double vertices" but I just can't find that option to remove those extra vertices.

Also i tried with the Merge By Distance option but i still see 13 vertices where it should be 9 vertices.

I want to remove double vertices between the triangle plane and the top of the cube

Please help  Sir,

[image]

Comment: Temporarily, turn off your mirror modifier. Every new vertex you create, mirror modifier creates its double.

Comment: If asnwer didnt help, click on vertex and move it side to see if there are two. Because from your desciption seems like these four vertices are totaly somewhere else. Or go to Preferences > Interface > Display > Developers Extras switch ON. Go to Viewports Overlay  > Mesh Edit Mode > Developers > Indices switch ON and check if there are overlaping numbers.

Comment: Or since this is going to be strange (because from your screen you have selected 8 vertices, so there is no reason why it souldnt  be posssible to Merge by Distance) post a blend file https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Answer (score 0):

Merge by distance should fix your problem, but you need to select the entire model. If it still doesn't work try increasing the merge distance.

Try identifying of which vertices you have duplicates by using the box select tool on one of them and paying attention to the bottom left of the window. If it says "Verts: 2/13" you press "alt + m" and click on "at center". Repeat this until all duplicates are gone.

Comment: No i tried that , but still its not working , showing removed 0 vertices , also i increased the merge distance to 0.12m still no help, same thing ,

Answer (score 0):

## TLDR

Merge by distance and increase the distance until they disappear. If your cube is the default cube and units are the same, then you can merge up to 1.99 meters without affecting the mesh.

## The longer version.

Click on the object, go into edit mode. Make sure Xray mode is on (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> is the default shortcut) and select the vertices you want to merge, you don't have to select all of them if you don't want to.

Then go to *Mesh > Clean Up > Merge by distance* (or just press F3 and type `merge by distance`). Then use the operation button at the bottom left to increase the distance until the unwanted verts are gone but not too far that it affects other parts of your mesh.

If you still can't get rid of them this way for some reason, the other thing you could do is select the unwanted verts (outside of *Xray* mode) and press <kbd>X</kbd> > dissolve vertices. If the result isn't what wanted, try the other verts, maybe one at a time if in this case it's just four that you're worried about.

[image]